# How does WordPress.com resize images dynamically?

Tags: php, wordpress, image-resizing, dynamic-image-generation, wordpress.com

***NOTE:** This question is tricky (to decide whether it pertains to SO or not), but this is no simple WordPress question.*

I've heard that WordPress.com has a separate layer of infrastructure (Nginx based servers) for images that is pretty much independent of the hosted WordPress blogs.

The thing is, any image on a WordPress.com blog can be resized simply by appending `w` (width) and/or `h` (height) parameters like so:

`http://serenescribe.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/cropped-p1000206.jpg?w=400`
`http://serenescribe.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/cropped-p1000206.jpg?h=200`

Is the script available on the web? (Because, they [always say](http://automattic.com/work-with-us/) *"We’re strong believers in Open Source, and we try to open source everything we can."*)

Most of the dynamic image resizing scripts out there are insecure and very vulnerable to attacks (Tim Thumb), or badly written, or come at the cost of performance. Is/Are there any good ones?

**PS:** There are probably several other dynamic image resizing scripts, like TimThumb, for example. But I am only interested in what WordPress.com blogs use.

Comment: So what is the issue? Do you know how to resize images? Do you know ho to retrieve parameter value from the url?

Comment: I think what he is trying to point out is the hypocritcy of wp (if verfied to be true).

Comment: @zerkms I am looking for that script -- seeing if it's available, and open source.

Comment: @geekpanth3r: what for? The logic of such script is pretty simple

Comment: @zerkms Edited my question to reflect what I exactly want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(1)** Use TimThumb, then re-sizing your images is as simple as appending some parameters:

`http://example.com/timtumb.php?src=wp-content/uploads/2010/03/high_res_horsey.png&w=300&h=100`

**(2)** Then add these rewrite rules in your site's root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (w|h)=(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /full/path/to/timthumb.php?src=$1&%1=%2&%3=%4 [L]
```

Quick breakdown of the rules:

1. Check that the URI exists as a file.
2. Check that the URI in question is an image. Expand to other formats as needed.
3. Check that one or both of width and height are being altered.
4. Pass the file following to timthumb as variables:

   - $1 = filename
   - %1 = w or h
   - %2 = value of w or h
   - %3 = w or h
   - %4 = value of w or h

**(3)** Now, you can pretty much resize your images as you would on WordPress.com, i.e. like so:

`http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/high_res_horsey.png?w=300&h=100`

From http://www.myrant.net/2011/03/07/mimicking-wordpress-coms-image-resize-uris/

Comment: If you look at my my PS, I actually said against TimThumb. And by the way, I did come across this link when I googled my question before asking it here. Anyway, this seems to be the only choice I've got, and hence, I take yours for an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple plugin that might help others based on the solution provided by markratledge.

You can find it on https://github.com/ubc/wave-resize-image.

Make sure to update your .htaccess file as described in the readme.txt for it to work.